# How to import directory structure to org-mode heading?

Tags: directory

I can show directory structure in emacs using `M-! tree --dirfirst` according to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432531/is-there-an-emacs-tool-to-show-a-directory-structure-as-a-tree). But how to import a directory structure to emacs or org-mode heading ?

I want to have like:

```
- directory A
- directory AA
  - file A
- directory B
  - file B
- directory C
  - file C
```

Is there any workaround?

I tried using freeplane to import my folder structure, but always get `wrong type argument p` when importing to org file using org-freemind. using `org-toggle-heading` also does not help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `org-fstree` (install from MELPA or from [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/org-fstree.git)).  It seems to do exactly what you want, it even makes each heading be a link to the corresponding file or folder.

To use it, just put a line

```
#+BEGIN_FSTREE: ~/path/to/folder
```

in your org file and type `C-c C-c` on it. This will create a copy of the directory tree mapped to nested org headlines.

A few caveats:

1. Every time you do `C-c C-c` on the `#+BEGIN_FSTREE` line, the whole set of headings is **replaced**, including any text you may have typed under the headings. So, if you do want to add your own notes to the tree, you probably want to delete the `#+BEGIN_FSTREE` line after you have used it.
2. It adds a lot of trailing blanks to each header line.  You can remove these with `M-x delete-trailing-whitespace`
3. I don't think it is strictly valid org syntax to nest headings inside a `#+BEGIN ... #+END` structure.

Here is an example of what it produces:

```
* Trying out org-fstree
#+BEGIN_FSTREE: fstree-test-folder :relative-links t

** |D| [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-A][directory-A]]
** |D| [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-AA][directory-AA]]
*** | | [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-AA/file-A][file-A]]
** |D| [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-B][directory-B]]
*** | | [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-B/file-B][file-B]]
** |D| [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-C][directory-C]]
*** | | [[file:fstree-test-folder/directory-C/file-C][file-C]]


#+END_FSTREE
```

Of course, in emacs it looks nicer than that since the links only show the description part by default.

Answer (score 5):

Try `C-u M-!` and inserting the output from commands below that I adopted from [another question / Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14223233/2029311)

```
find . |sort|sed -E -e 's;(^.*[^/]/);\1 ;;s;([^/]*/);*;g;s/^\.$//'
```

That will give you a directory listing as headings, for example

```
* dir1
** file1
** file2
* dir2
** file1
* dir3
```

Select the region and convert headings to a lists using `C-c -`

```
- dir1
  - file1
  - file2
- dir2
  - file1
- dir3
```

Comment: This is clever, but it creates headlines rather than plain lists. I assume changing this example to use that format is trivial enough. Can you provide it as well, along with examples of how output of each of them looks like?

Comment: Ah yes.  I was looking at the previous answer which gave headlines.  As you rightly say the original question was for lists...  Shall update when I get the opportunity.

Comment: As suggested, added example output and instruction on how to change Headings into a list using org rather than modifying sed command.  Improved upon the command line too, adding sort and removing parent directory (.) within sed.